# Remove time in datetime python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, datetime, datetime-format

I have to remove time alone from this date and time format "01/31/2000 09:09 PM".

But I want to remove the 09:09 PM(time) for this value in my templates file. How could I do this?

I am try this:

datetime.strptime("01/31/2000 09:09 PM", "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%p")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions in this case:

```
>>> s = "01/31/2000 09:09 PM"
>>> date, space, time = s.partition(' ')
>>> date
'01/31/2000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Through `re` module.

```
>>> s = "01/31/2000 09:09 PM"
>>> re.sub(r'\s.*', '', s)
'01/31/2000'
```

This would replace all the characters from the first space until the end with an empty string.